# MySQL to refresh memcached

Tags: php, mysql, memcached, lamp

We have a web application running on LAMP stack, the application depends on various services. These services gets data from cache (memcached) which is being refreshed using cron (from MySQL). Cron processes are running every 5 mins.

In this approach we can not serve data which is updated recently as cache is getting refreshed every 5 mins.

Is there any mechanism exists which can trigger cache refresh as soon as data gets updated in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but what you can do is create MySQL trigger which gets executed on insert/update/delete.

Inside that MySQL trigger execute a `UDF`. From that `UDF` you can execute any PHP script using `sys_exec()`.

[Read about Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

[Read about UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html)

[Read about using `sys_exec()` and more](http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.in/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html)

Comment: I used a similar thing to fire a CURL request when data gets changed in MySQL table.

Comment: Hi Manu, What i have heard from friends that trigger locks the table or row which result in failure of subsequent queries. Is it true?

Comment: Your queries won't fail. They just might have to wait. I think in case of InnoDB it will lock the row, and in case of MyISAM it will lock the table.. But I am not sure about about this one. I suggest you ask another question about this thing.. :P Post the link of that question here too. :D

Comment: BTW, how much time does your PHP script take to refresh the memcache? If its 1-3 seconds then ideally it should not be an issue.

Comment: Hi Manu, Its 5 mins, anything less than this is not feasible.

Comment: And how often does your table get updated? If its getting updated too frequently then you should not memcache it at all.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this problem was to have the MySQL query in a function with the memcached query, for example (in Python, because I don't know PHP, you can look at it an change it to PHP):

```
def insert(user,value):
 #execute on memcached first
 key="user:"+user
 memcClient.set(key,value)
 #then execute it on MySQL
 cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tables VALUES (%s,%s)",(user,value))
 db.commit()
```

And you will do the same for delete and update, sorry I couldn't do it in PHP, I'm just a teen coder, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What about identifying the mysql updation at php level only & refresh the memcache accordingly ?

```
<?php

if($update_db){  // if we need to update the db then update db & memcacache together !

// Code to Update the database ....

// Code to Reset the memcached keyvalue pair.

}

?>
```

In the approach suggested by Manu, we are using expensive db trigger which is actually not needed to achieve the cache update.

Comment: Hi Sumoanand, thanks but there are disadvantages of this approach as PHP has to trigger 2 updates which will reduce the performance.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get it. These two updates anyway you performing unless my understanding is incorrect. Your flow is: Db update(update 1) -> db trigger -> memcache update(update 2).

Comment: I mean response time to request.